# Angular library project import npm package theme css

Tags: angular, npm

I have an Angular library project which has a component "pseudo". There is a main project that will use the library project. In the component "pseudo" (library project) I am using a 3rd party npm package

```
pseudo
|-- pseudo.component.html
|-- pseudo.component.scss
|-- pseudo.component.ts
```

Now I also need to import a 3rd party theme css. I tried multiple ways but cannot figure out.
I tried using @import in `pseudo.component.scss` but it didn't work in the main project (that uses this library project)

```
@import '~@ng-3rd/ng-3rd/themes/default.theme.css';
```

I also tried use the `styleUrls` in `pseudo.component.ts` that didn't work either.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-pseudo',
  templateUrl: './pseudo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pseudo.component.scss', '../../../../../../node_modules/@ng-3rd/ng-3rd/themes/default.theme.css']
})
```

I couldn't get the styles working in main project (which uses library project)

The library project using ng-package.json

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it in your style by adding it in your style array in angular.json file:

```
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/patient-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.webmanifest"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
          "node_modules/path/to/the/style.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
          "moment-timezone",
          "qrcode"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Thank you Adnan. After adding styles I am getting the error:
Schema validation failed with the following errors:  'Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles)'

Also notably the library project using ng-package.json